# Mass Text to Speech using Plivo

Tags: plivo

I am looking at integrating Plivo with our platform to make outgoing text to speech calls.  All of our calls made, will be a customized message of about 20 words, or less than a 30 second call.

Daily, we'll batch about 10,000 calls at the same time.  It appears I would have to make 10,000 rest API calls vs being able to send a batch at one time, each one with it's own answer_url.  Does anyone have experience with this, seems like a ton of overhead.

Another option may be to use parameters in the answer_url, so I can send a list of all phone numbers at once and then based on a parameterized answer_url, tell Plivo what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

With Plivo, you can make bulk outbound calls where you can specify multiple numbers and a single answer_url. See https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/make-bulk-calls/ for a getting started doc.

For each call made, Plivo makes a request to that answer url with the to/from numbers (see [this link](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/making-outbound-calls/#parameters-sent-to-the-answerurl) for more details). Then, based on the to/from numbers, your answer_url can respond with the TTS message to be played for that particular number. You would just need to have a database where you can lookup the number to get the message to play for each request to your answer_url.